# What is the order of ringing the bells for the quest Buried Secrets?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I am in Gilded Vale in the Temple of Eothas. A door with a rather high lockpick check is hindering my way. In what order do have to sound the bells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order is:

- Right
- Middle
- Left
- Right